# Confusion regarding continuous functions between topological spaces – a subtle but possibly important point

Tags: general-topology, terminology

> Let $T: V_1 \to V_2$ be a linear mapping. Show that $T$ is a continuous function between $(V_1, \tau_{V_1}) $ and $(V_2, \tau_{V_2}) $

A direct solution to the problem is not what I am looking for but actually whether an interpretation of the question is correct because I have done the problem and know the solution entails taking a composition of continuous functions. But I am now doing another question of similar style now and then as now the composition to use is driving me insane.

So my question is this: *is a continuous function between two sets the same as a continuous function between two topological spaces?* I ask because in taking the composition of a group of continuous functions, one of the functions in the composition is specifically the function $T$, but now i'm confused because I thought the function $T$ was the one that we are trying to show is continuous. Hence why I ask the question.

Comment: You usually need a topology to talk about continuity, but you may also use the fact that a linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces is continuous. Still, this uses a norm, which gives rise to a topology.

Comment: There are no continuous functions between sets unless the sets are both equipped with a topology.

Comment: If the topology on the domain space is discrete, all functions are continuous, no matter the topology of the codomain.

Comment: So then why/how is it that i end up using the same function that i am trying to prove is continuous in my compositions. Right now i am trying to show that $g (A) = det(A) $ is continuous, but i end up having to use this same determinant function within my set of compositions.....

Comment: @dc3rd: But continuity of determinant depends on a continuity defined on matrices.

Comment: Within my earlier results i proved the contintuity between vector spaces as well as thier homeomorphisms. Maybe i am thinking in circles but i just can't grasp showing the continuity of a function while using said function..